# expand werkzeug useragent class

Tags: python, flask, user-agent, werkzeug

I want to expand werkzeug UserAgent class with one more browser. How can I do it without modifying the source code of werkzeug library? I'm new in python so I have small idea about mixins, inheritance, modules and so on.
I've found in docs:

> It’s a good idea to create a custom subclass of the BaseRequest and add missing functionality either via mixins or direct implementation. Here an example for such subclasses:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseRequest, ETagRequestMixin
class Request(BaseRequest, ETagRequestMixin):
    pass
```

At which part of my code should I put this and how to expand standart UserAgent class? Also I'm using werkzeug with Flask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazing. Once you ask question the answer comes up itself :)

[`Flask.request_class`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.request_class) is the answer:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseRequest, ETagRequestMixin

class Request(BaseRequest, ETagRequestMixin): 
    pass

app = Flask(__name__)
app.request_class = Request
```